# How to get softlayer operatingSystemReferenceCode list for custom bare metal servers

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

It looks like that SoftLayer_Hardware::getCreateObjectOptions provides the list of operatingSystemReferenceCode for pre-set configured bare metal servers. Is there any way to get the list of operatingSystemReferenceCode for custom bare metal servers?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by "custom bare metal servers", the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_server/createObject method allows you to customise all te options detailed in the documentation such as hard drives capacity or proccess core amount and Yes the operatingSystemReferenceCode list returned for SoftLayer_Hardware::getCreateObjectOptions works for create those bare metal server.

Now if you are looking for getting the same Operating System list like the control portal displays you need to use a different method to order and a different method to get the Bare metal server options. To order you need to use the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder method and to get the bare metal vailable options (included the OSs) you need to use the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices or the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems methods. Here you can get more information about the placeOrder method http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3

Comment: I have no idea what is the official offering name. I used the terminologies in the blog: http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/ordering-bare-metal-servers-using-softlayer-api. SoftLayer_Hardware::getCreateObjectOptions does not return entire os reference codes for monthly bare metal server. For example, it does not return WIN_2012-DC-R2_64. getItems returns keyName and priceId of OS for specific monthly bare metal server package. But, that keyName is not an os reference code.

Comment: that is likely an issue I recomend you to open a tickect and ask to add that OS in the list returned by SoftLayer_Hardware::getCreateObjectOptions

Comment: WIN_2012-DC-R2_64 is just an example. It looks like that  SoftLayer_Hardware::getCreateObjectOptions only returns available OSs for pre-configured(?) bare metal server. Is there any method which returns os reference codes for monthly(?) bare metal servers?

Comment: Well the method that you want to use has been design to order bare metal server in a simplified way, so it has limitations you can not order all the same options as you could do using the control portal keep that in mind, The OS listed for SoftLayer_Hardware::getCreateObjectOptions  should work for mountly servers as well (renember that for to set the server as mountly you need to set the variable hourlyBillingFlag property to false) and another thing that you keep in mind is that you only can order server that belong to the package 200, but with the portal there are more packages available